# MySQLi one ID has more Records

Tags: php, mysql

Hello I have a table where timestamps are stored the timestamps from one item have all the same ID now I want to have only the smallest timestamp from every item.

Here is what I have:

```
$timeArr = array(23700, 23699, 23704, 23864);
foreach ($timeArr as $hido) {
    $mysqli = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "password", "dbname");
    if (!$mysqli) {
        die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
    }
    $sql = "SELECT clock FROM trends WHERE itemid = '$hido'";
    $re = mysqli_query($mysqli, $sql);
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($re)) {

        $time = $row['clock'];


}

mysqli_free_result($re);
mysqli_close($mysqli);


}
```

I want to have only the smallest/oldest record of every itemid how can I do that?

**EDIT:** The timestamps should be in the same order as the Id's in the array.

Comment: Are you after the smallest `clock` for each of the items in your `$timeArr` or only one result i.e. the smallest `clock` from any of the `$timeArr` itemid's

Comment: I'm after the smallest clock of each item. In the end it should be like this:    itemid1: smallest clock  itemid2: smallestclock.....

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
SELECT MIN(clock) FROM trends group by itemid
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$sql = "SELECT clock FROM trends WHERE itemid = '$hido' ORDER BY clock ASC LIMIT 1";
```

Answer (score -1):

You will need to capture more than one result so I have changed the code to save the MIN `clock` into an array indexed by the `$hido` value.

Also you should only `connnect` to the database once, then do as many queries as you like, rather than connect each time you want to run a query, so I have reordered the code a little

```
$mysqli = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "password", "dbname");
if (!$mysqli) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

$timeArr = array(23700, 23699, 23704, 23864);
$times = array();  // hold the min time for each itemid

foreach ($timeArr as $hido) {
    $sql = "SELECT MIN(clock) FROM trends WHERE itemid = '$hido'";

    $re = mysqli_query($mysqli, $sql);
    if ( ! $re ) {
        echo 'Connection failed: ' . mysqli_error();
        exit;
    }

    // as using MIN will mean you only get one row in your result set
    // you no longer need a while loop to process multiple result rows.
    $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($re);

    $times[$hido] = $row['clock'];

    mysqli_free_result($re);
}


mysqli_close($mysqli);
```

Comment: Ok, now you have explained the requirement better, I have changed the answer accordingly. Thanks to whoever hit this with a DV by the way.